# JavaScript and HTML5 canvas (basic) issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to learn how to use a canvas and i cannot for the life of me figure out why this basic code wont work does anyone know what I am doing incorrect?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/942vr/)

```
<canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000"></canvas>
 <script >

 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 ctx.fillText = ("hey", 50, 50);

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the wrong ID to `getElementById`. Your canvas id is `ctx` not `canvas`. Use `document.getElementById('ctx').`